# Connecting 2 Forms together

Tags: vb.net

I am wanting 2 Forms to connect to each other like this:[image]

but how would I do that? Can I even do that?

Comment: Like _how_? What I see is one form and four images.

Comment: What do you mean by "2 forms to connect"? Do you want them to connect via code? or just combine each form into 1?

Comment: Sure. You can adjust the side form location in the main form's [`.Layout`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.layout) Event

Comment: Well I want them to suppose be in 1 form but since I am new to vb idk how to do it. I moved it to that location. Slai, can you please explain what that means with 2 forms unless I can combine into 1 form?

Comment: Set the small form's `TopLevel` property to `False`, then call `yourBigForm.Controls.Add(yourSmallForm)`. That will place the small form inside the bigger form.

Comment: Where would I put the yourBigForm.Controls.Add(yourSmallForm) at?